# TypeScript doesn`t know the correct return type of array.pop()

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
// (weekdays is of type string[])

if (weekdays?.length) {
  const sunday = weekdays.pop();
  weekdays.unshift(sunday);
}
```

Here, TypeScript gives an error because it says weekdays.pop() returns `string | undefined`, but since i`m checking if the array is empty, the .pop() should aways return `string`.

What is the best way to solve this problem? (without using "as" or "ts-ignore")

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiKFb.png)

Comment: TypeScript does know the correct return type of `array.pop()`. But it does not understand the code. It can narrow some types in conditional statements based on some common situations that have been coded into it. It cannot narrow the type here and in a zillion other cases.

Comment: @Terry thanks, that`s what i was looking for.